# Why the sum of model.predict(x) is less than 1 with softmax and LSTM?

Tags: keras

I'm using keras, and the final layer uses a 'softmax' activation function.
However, when I use predict and sum the probabilities, I do not get 1.
Why is that?

N.B. :
I am really far from 1:

```
>>> m
<keras.models.Sequential object at 0x1083fdf60>
>>> m.layers[-1].activation
<function softmax at 0x1092bfea0>
>>> X.shape
(1940, 10, 48)
>>> m.input
<tf.Tensor 'lstm_1_input:0' shape=(?, 10, 48) dtype=float32>
>>> model.predict(X)[:10].sum(axis=-1)
array([ 0.46206102,  0.43193966,  0.4252567 ,  0.44023705,  0.46344867,
        0.48820126,  0.50369406,  0.49789378,  0.46433908,  0.44102359], dtype=float32)
>>> y=model.predict(X)
>>> y[0]
array([  0.00000000e+00,   6.10233226e-04,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.12394022e-03,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,   1.55960268e-04,   0.00000000e+00,
         4.60170895e-01], dtype=float32)
```

EDIT:
I tested with a simple code

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import *
m = Sequential()
m.add(LSTM(3, input_shape=(3,2), activation='softmax'))
print(m.predict(np.random.rand(5,3,2)).sum(axis=-1))
```

And I get results like

```
[ 0.50027865  0.49804032  0.49545377  0.50514281  0.50069857]
```

OKAY, so with Dense and SimpleRNN, I get almost 1. The problem might simply be that activation has not the same behaviour with recurrent layers, since GRU has the same issues.
I asked on GitHub: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/6255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@joelthchao said on GitHub (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/6255):

> Activation here is directly apply on each hidden unit. However, we won't use LSTM in this way. Usually, we do it by:

```
m.add(LSTM(hidden_unit, input_shape=(3,2)))
m.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

Finally, I found more logical to use :

```
m.add(Lambda(K.softmax))
```

Answer (score 1):

By construction, the softmax prediction should sum to one.  However, in practice, they might not sum to exactly one due to the limits of machine precision. How far from 1 are your cumulative probabilities?

I ran the mnist_mlp.py example found in the Keras example/ directory with Theano as the backend. Then I predicted the test set probabilities with the trained model.  The probabilities sum to almost one, as expected.

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
y_sum = y_pred.sum(axis=1)
print('Min={}, Max={}, Range={}'.format(y_sum.min(),y_sum.max(),y_sum.max()-y_sum.min()))
# Min=0.9999999403953552, Max=1.0000001192092896, Range=1.7881393432617188e-07
```

The observed range is on the same order as machine epsilon for 32 bit floats.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.finfo(np.float32).eps)
#1.19209e-07
```

which is consistent with the use of

```
      "floatx": "float32",
```

in my ~/.keras/keras.hjson file.  If you need additional precision, you can can change "float32" to "float64".

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more precise! I am very far from 1…

Comment: @Labo Could it be an underflow/overflow issue?
  This [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149663/robust-softmax-solutions-for-theano) on robust softmax solution may be relevant.

Comment: I had overflows in Keras, and it generally causes "nan" to appear as values. I have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: As you can see in my edit, I have the same problem even with a simple model.